# About AppEUI for I-NUCLEO-LRWAN1

Tags: stm32, lorawan

I have a P-NUCLEO-LRWAN2 (I-NUCLEO-LRWAN1 and a RisingHF gateway) starter pack.
Following the UM2587 user manual from ST, the NUCLEO-L073RZ comes with preloaded firmware that reads the DevEUI and AppEUI keys from the sensor board. You can read the values from memory 0x08080000 and 0x08080008. The DevEUI key corresponds to that of a sticker on the package, but the AppEUI key is zero. Furthermore, I'm not able to set a new key using the AT_Master project with added code snippet:

```
uint8_t AppID[8] = MY_STICKER_KEY;
uint8_t *PtrAppID = &AppID;
    
LoRa_SetAppID(PtrAppID);
```

Should the code-snippet be sufficient when appended to the AT_Master project ?

I can see the gateway on a Loriot network, and I'm able to *enroll device* in the sample application at Loriot, but the sensor is never seen. I've tried a AppEUI (JoinEUI) of zeros only, but that did not work. Am I forced to use the AppEUI from the sticker, or can I choose another key ?